# Css svg image Before change fill

Tags: css, html, svg

I am adding to a HTML class  a "before" css for a SVG image in menu.
I what to change the color of the SVG.
All that I tryed  does not work for me.
Can some one help please Thanks

This if the css.

```
.selectdesing:before{
  content: url("data:image/svg+xml; utf8, <svg version='1.1' id='Isolation_Mode' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' x='0px' y='0px' viewBox='0 0 300 295'><g><path d='M300,0H0v295h300V0z M290.2,285.2H9.8v-74l67.1-58.4l31.3,27.2l43.6-44.1l75.9,65.8l30.8-26.7l31.6,27.4V285.2z M290.2,189.3l-31.6-27.4l-30.8,26.7l-76.5-66.2l-43.6,44.1l-30.8-26.7L9.8,198.2V9.8h280.4V189.3z'/><path d='M228.5,137.5c12.9,0,23.4-10.5,23.4-23.4c0-12.9-10.5-23.4-23.4-23.4c-12.9,0-23.4,10.5-23.4,23.4C205.1,127,215.6,137.5,228.5,137.5z M228.5,100.5c7.5,0,13.6,6.1,13.6,13.6c0,7.5-6.1,13.6-13.6,13.6c-7.5,0-13.6-6.1-13.6-13.6C214.9,106.6,221,100.5,228.5,100.5z'/></g></svg>");
display:block;
width:22px;
height:10px;
margin:10px 5px 0 10px;
}
```

Comment: This question makes as much sense backwards as it does forwards

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you want to change the colour of an element in the SVG with CSS, then you are out of luck.  The best you could do is replace the `content` with a different DataURI that has the colour modified.

The reason is that when an external SVG is loaded as an image, it is basically the same as if it was a PNG. Its DOM is inaccessible and thus nothing in it can be references with a CSS selector.